# How to configure the Sherlock Action Bar + the map plugin?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Because it takes me a lot of time to integrate the Sherlock Action Bar in my Android project (with its map plugin !), I propose to depict here my solution.

Comment: Download the Google APIs and add the "maps.jar" to your "libs" folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First step consists to create a library project, second to create your own project that will use the Action Bar and third step enables to use the map plugin.

I - ActionBar SHerlock project :

1. download the actionbarSherlock zip file
2. import existing Android code into Workspace (for ActionBar 4.2.0). select the directory "library" to import. A "library" project is created.
3. set your manifest with "android:minSdkVersion="7" 
   android:targetSdkVersion="16"
4. Import compatibility library: right click on the project > Android
   Tools > Add Support Library
5. configure this project with the following Project properties :

   - android build target : >= android 4.0
   - check "Is Library"

II - Your project :

1. create your project that use Action Bar sherlock
2. set Android Build Target to >= Android 4.0 (choose the same target
   than the previous project !)
3. set your manifest with "android:minSdkVersion="7" 
   android:targetSdkVersion="16"
4. add the previous project "ActionBarSherlock" as a library : Project > Properties > Android > Add... (bottom panel)
5. Change your code to use the ActionBar classes

III - To use the actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar plugin of Action Bar Sherlock :

1. add the actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar (obtained from the
   zip file) to the project "ActionBarSherlock" in the libs directory
2. configure the project : project > properties > build path >
   Librairies :

   ```
   - add actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar
   ```
3. set the build target to Google map API >4.0 (do the same for your project - same target !)
4. add the "actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar" library to the new project’s build path

I Hope it will also work for you.

Comment: How should I remove the `android-support-v4.jar` from the build path? It is only listed as an item in `Android Dependencies`. I cannot remove the actual file from the `libs` folder since there are dependencies.. - When I setup an example project as you described I always end up with a `ClassNotFoundException` when I run the app.

Comment: also you need java set to 1.6 when compiling and change the compiler's option from Eclipse->preferences-> "Potential null pointer access" to Warning instead of Error

Comment: I don't see that actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar file in the zip file that I downloaded?

Comment: This plugin is not included by default : http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html